# Changing TextView Background color on touch

Tags: android, textview, background-color

I want to change Background color of a textview when click or touch it.
this is textview

```
<com.example.shuvo.KeyboardButton
                android:id="@+id/showMenuButton"
                style="@drawable/color"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:text="Menu"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_link_selector"
                android:background="@drawable/keyboard"
                 />
```

In keyboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true">  <color android:color="#00ff00" /> </item>
```

And in keyboardButton.java

```
public class KeyboardButton extends TextView {

public KeyboardButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public KeyboardButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public KeyboardButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setLayoutParams(int width, int height) {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, 60);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.keyboard);
    setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

}

This not working. Where is the problem?

Comment: where is the code for `onTouch()`?

Comment: No need to solve this problem dynamically with java, By adding `android:clickable="true"` inside textview, will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i solved this Problem just now. Need to add `android:clickable="true"` in custom textview. Now this is working fine. But i keep this question to help others.

Answer (score 4):

Create .xml file in drawable folder and put this code inside

```
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

After this set this xml as a background in textview

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/yourxmlfile" />
```

Comment: To change bg color on click need to add `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: yes but default text view is clickable so no need to add if your text view doesn’t  response then put this line inside textview.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is using a selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

In the Activity also we can change it like

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      switch(event.getAction())
      {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
              lastY = event.getY();
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              float abs = Math.abs(lastY - event.getY());

              if(abs > TIME_DELAY) // TIME_DELAY=2
                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
              break;
      }
      return true;
  }
});
```

You can change the time delay as low as possible so that the background changes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use onTouchListener or onClickListener:

```
    final com.example.shuvo.KeyboardButton text = findViewById(R.id.showMenuButton);
    text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // change the background color
            text.setBackgroundColor(color);
            text.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
            text.setTextColor(color);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It will change only the bg on press and then doesnt change back. You have to check `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)` and `ACTION_UP`. But this is buggy because if you hold and swipe to the left or right on the button, the bg color will stay the same and will not change back unless you tap it again to reset it

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees yeah you are right, but I believe the OP is asking only about changing the background one time when click the button, not having a press-release effect.